# How to design a matrix with multiple chosen eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cyclotomic-polynomials

I want to "design" (build) a matrix that have multiple known eigenvalues. For these apriori chosen eigenvalues, I want to know the corresponding eigenvectors, too.

The point is that I want to start from the eigenvalues, chose the eigenvectors appropriately and then compute the matrix. All values must be integers.

I need this for a cryptographic application. Namely, I'm looking for something similar to [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), but done with eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
To make an idea, in paper [Fully Homomorphic SIMD Operations](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/133.pdf) the authors propose an improvement upon previous schemes. They choose a specific cyclotomic polynomial which factorizes in n polynomials and so they can encrypt n message at a time. I want the same but for the [approximate eigenvector problem](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/340.pdf).

Comment: Look at the Jordan form

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Jordan form seems a good start.

Comment: Do you mean you want to freely choose both the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors and then figure out what the matrix should be?  If that's it, then it's not a hard problem, but at this point I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to do. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, @MichaelHardy. That's  what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want to freely choose eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  So you've chosen eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ and respective eigenvectors $\vec v_1,\ldots,\vec v_n$.  You want a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ for which $A\vec v_i = \lambda_i\vec v_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Let $V= \big[ \vec v_1,\ \ldots\ ,\ \vec v_n \big] \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$.  Let
$$
\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_2 \\  & & \lambda_3 \\ & & & \ddots \\ & & & & \lambda_n  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then
$$
A = V \Lambda V^{-1}
$$
will do the trick.  Observe that
$$
V^{-1} \vec v_i = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\  \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \vec e_i \qquad \text{(with a 1 only in the $i$th position)},
$$
and
$$
\Lambda \vec e_i = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\  \vdots \\ 0 \\ \lambda_i \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda_i \vec e_i \qquad \text{(with $\lambda_i$ only in the $i$th position)},
$$
and finally
$$
V(\lambda_i \vec e_i) = \lambda_i \vec v_i,
$$
so
$$
(V\Lambda V^{-1}) \vec v_i = \lambda_i \vec v_i.
$$